# Cant locate element(id) using pycharm/appium server(1.15.1) for mobile app. But same element can be located by Appium Studio

Tags: appium

self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath=//*[@id='text1']").click()

Above code works perfect in appium studio where it clicks the element but when i initiate the app thru pycharm, it land on to the app and displays the element still error is there that no element exists.

Appium-python client version 0.50
Appium server version 1.15.1
selenium version 3.141.0

Comment: copy the xpath from appium desktop app and use that xpath to select element

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath=//*[@id='text1']").click()
```

for

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='text1']").click()
```

Comment: I tried using find_element_by_id also, but it looks like find_element itself is not working.Anyways the above same line works in Appium studio.I changed my line with the line given by u still it doesnt work. There is some issue with find_element thing but not able to understand

Comment: can you try what i suggested? and post the failure logs?
also, try storing the element in a variable and print its size before clicking it, just to see if is actually found.

Comment: I used the locator u gave, size is not printed as element cant be found. I get below errorself = <appium.webdriver.errorhandler.MobileErrorHandler object at 0x0000000003E7B2B0>
response = {'status': 404, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"An element could not be located on the page u...ces\\\\app\\\\node_modules\\\\appium\\\\node_modules\\\\appium-android-driver\\\\lib\\\\commands\\\\find.js:75:11)"}}'}

Comment: it clearly says that it does not exist, so one of two things, locator is wrong, (are you using the appium inspector to get the element name?) and try to add a wait on the element so it clicked only if it is found, maybe appium is too fast it tried clicking it before it exists in the DOM

Comment: The same locator work in Appium studio when I record and replay but does not work in Appium, Today I tried in morning and changed locator from id to class_name and it works. I think I was giving wrong locator in pycharm but i am quite still surprised why same locator working in Appium studio does not work in Appium

Comment: i will be good if you posted your code working as an example of how you solved the issue